# Debugger doesn't reach "BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()"

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to register a BroadcastReceiver out of a Service to check for WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION in the Background. So far so good - no compiler errors .. But!

Whatever I've done or tried, I never reached my onReceive() code.
I'm testing on my hardware device, turning on and off wifi, but nothing happens. As well I registered the service/Receiver in my manifest, did everything I found from demos and tutorials and books^^
(I'm using the service just to let the BroadcastReceiver run in the background and act if its necessary..)

So here's my code:

**"My Activity class"**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(this, IntelliRingService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**"My Service class"**

```
public class IntelliRingService extends Service {


    public BroadcastReceiver myWifiBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION))
            {
                // DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        IntentFilter theFilter;
        theFilter = new IntentFilter();
        theFilter.addAction(WIFI_SERVICE);

        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(myWifiBroadcastReceiver, theFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(myWifiBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do when you receive a broadcast (I mean how much work)? If you want to do some simple work you can just do it in the Broadcast Receiver's `onReceive` method. If you want to do a lot of work then you can start you service from your Broadcast Receiver. In this case you won't have to run your service all the time.